# C++ My files were working before I attempted to move them into a source file, and now there are no errors and nothing being displayed

Tags: c++

My apologies for being a little vague about the issue(s) in the topic, but I really am not sure. I am attempting to create a course_directory as a lab project for school, and up until now everything had been progressing quite well. I have written and tested each of the function in the main.cpp before attempting to move the class functions into the .hpp file. My goal is to have nothing in main except for a call to "Run" that will open a file, and in turn make a call to "displayMenu", and allow the user to interact with the information as they choose, but now everything is compiling correctly, and nothing is being displayed.

Course_directory.hpp

```
#include "Course_Directory.h"

using namespace std;

Course_Directory::Course_Directory(){};
Course_Directory courses[1001];

void Course_Directory::displayMenu(){
cout << "1.Print all courses" << endl;
cout << "2.Print all courses for a department" << endl;
cout << "3.Print roster for a course" << endl;
cout << "4.Print the largest class" << endl;
cout << "5.Swap two classes" << endl;
cout << "6.Print schedule for a student" << endl;
cout << "7.Exit" << endl;

char dept[50], dept2[50];
int courseNo, courseNo2, i, choice;

while (choice != 7) {
    cout << "\nEnter your choice: ";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 1)
        printAllCourses(i);
    else if (choice == 2) {
        cout << "\nEnter department name:";
        cin >> dept;
    for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(dept); j++)
    {
        dept[j] = (toupper(dept[j]));
    }
        coursesInDept(dept, i);
    }
    else if (choice == 3) {
        cout << "\nEnter course number:";
        cin >> courseNo;
        studentsInCourse(courseNo, i);
    }
    else if (choice == 4) {
        largestClass(i);
    }
    else if (choice == 5) {
        cout << "\nEnter first department name :";
        cin >> dept;
        for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(dept); j++)
        {
            dept[j] = (toupper(dept[j]));
        }
        cout << "\nEnter first course number: ";
        cin >> courseNo;
        cout << "\nEnter second department name :";
        cin >> dept2;
        for(int k = 0; k < sizeof(dept2); k++)
        {
            dept2[k] = (toupper(dept2[k]));
        }
        cout << "\nEnter second course number: ";
        cin >> courseNo2;
        swap2(dept, courseNo, dept2, courseNo2, i);
    }
    else if (choice == 6) {
        int id;
        cout << "\nEnter a student Id:";
        cin >> id;
        schedule(id, i);
    }
}
cout << "Goodbye!\n";
}
void Course_Directory::printAllCourses(int len){
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    cout << "Course name: " << courses[i].courseName << ", Course 
number: " << courses[i].courseNum << endl;
    cout << len;
}
void Course_Directory::coursesInDept(char *dept, int len) {
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    if (strcmp(dept, courses[i].courseName) == 0)
        cout << "Course Name: " << courses[i].courseName << ", 
Course number: " << courses[i].courseNum << endl;
}

void Course_Directory::studentsInCourse(int courseNo, int len) {
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    if (courseNo == courses[i].courseNum) {
        for (int m = 0; m < courses[i].numStudents - 1; m++)
            cout << courses[i].IDs[m] << ",";
            cout << courses[i].IDs[courses[i].numStudents - 1] << 
endl;
    }
}

void Course_Directory::largestClass(int len) {
int max = -999;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (courses[i].numStudents > max)
        max = courses[i].numStudents;
}
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (courses[i].numStudents == max){
        cout << "\nThe largest class is in department: " << 
courses[i].courseName
        << ", and the course number is: " << courses[i].courseNum 
<< "\n";
        cout << "The class currently has " << max << " students 
enrolled.\n";
    }
}
}

void Course_Directory::swap2(char *firstDep, int firstNo, char 
*secondDep, int secondNo, int len) {
Course_Directory temp;
int firstIndex, secondIndex;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (strcmp(firstDep, courses[i].courseName) == 0 && 
courses[i].courseNum == firstNo)
        firstIndex = i;
    if (strcmp(secondDep, courses[i].courseName) == 0 && 
courses[i].courseNum == secondNo)
        secondIndex = i;
}
temp = courses[firstIndex];
courses[firstIndex] = courses[secondIndex];
courses[secondIndex] = temp;
}

void Course_Directory::schedule(int id, int len) {
cout << "Courses student " << id << " is enrolled in: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < courses[i].numStudents; j++)
        if (courses[i].IDs[j] == id)
            cout << courses[i].courseNum << " \n";
}
}
```

Course_Directory.h

```
#ifndef COURSE_DIRECTORY_H
#define COURSE_DIRECTORY_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Course_Directory{

private:
int* deptSize;
string filename;

public:
char courseName[1001];
int courseNum;
int numStudents;
int IDs[1001];
int* choice;
void displayMenu();
Course_Directory();
//Course_Directory(const Course_Directory& original);
//~Course_Directory();
//void run(string);
void coursesInDept(char*, int);
void studentsInCourse(int, int);
void largestClass(int);
void swap2(char*, int, char*, int, int);
void schedule(int, int);
void printAllCourses(int);


};
#include "Course_Directory.hpp"
#endif //COURSE_DIRECTORY_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Course_Directory.h"

using namespace std;
class Course_Directory;

int main() {

ifstream file;
file.open("input.txt");

char *token;
int i = 0, j;
Course_Directory courses[100];
if (!file.fail()) {
    std::string line;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        j = 0;
        char *str = const_cast<char *>(line.c_str());
        token = strtok(str, " ");
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            if (j == 0)
                strcpy(courses[i].courseName, token);
            else if (j == 1)
                courses[i].courseNum = atoi(token);
            else if (j == 2)
                courses[i].numStudents = atoi(token);
            else
                courses[i].IDs[j - 3] = atoi(token);
            j++;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            cout << courses[i].courseName << endl;
        }
        i++;
    }
    file.close();
}
else{
        cout << "File not found." << endl;
}
//menu
Course_Directory displayMenu();

return 0;
}
```

If I leave Course_Directory off of displayMenu(); then I get "displayMenu" was not declared in this scope. I'm not sure what the problem is or why the menu will not display. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `char *str = const_cast<char *>(line.c_str()); token = strtok(str, " ");` -- Don't do this.  If you want to know why, what was the reason for the cast?  Remove the cast, recompile, and read the compiler error carefully.  If you are returned a `const` anything, don't try and change it with casting tricks.  Your code now has undefined behavior with the `strtok` call.

Comment: @BrianClark please show me the compiler that would compile that code without errors. Also please give an example for "input.txt".

Comment: Also, the way you parse a space delimited string into tokens is easily done using `std::istringstream` without resorting to `strtok`.

Comment: Better yet, use `std::string` methods and forget about `strtok`.  Remember `strtok` *modifies` its argument.

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling the new file? IDEs can be a bit finicky about what they will and will not compile if the new file is not added correctly.

Comment: come to think of it,  Course_directory.hpp is probably a bad idea. You have data definitions in a header file and that rarely ends well. Make this into a cpp file and remove the include from Course_Directory.h.  Let the compiler compile. Maybe add an `extern` or two if main needs access to some of the data definitions.

Comment: Unrelated: [Your Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants to know what `i` is in `printAllCourses(i);`.

Comment: Swordfish if you read my original post, it IS compiling without a single error. The input file is....a single number (for the number of courses in the department) followed by MATH 526 4 73827 39282 83844 91918. That would be the department, followed by course number, number of students in the class, and a corresponding number of student ID's

Comment: I was just about to make a comment: Aha! The problem is that none of the files contain any functions - they're all just a bunch of code! On reflection, I'm going to change my comment to: Please please please consider indenting your code. It helps the reader to understand code flow enormously.

Comment: It is indented and looks much better in the compiler, but translating that to a post on here would have taken a lot more effort for little gain lol

Comment: Dare I ask, for what purpose did you put `class Course_Directory;` in `main.cpp` ? What did that "fix" ? Also, how does usage of `ifstream` even compile? It requires `<fstream>` which none of this code includes. Unrelated, in `displayMenu`, the code `while (choice != 7)` invokes undefined behavior. It is evaluating the local variable `choice` from two lines above, which is (a) hiding the member, and (b) is indeterminate.

Comment: @BrianClark 1. Paste code into editor window. 2. Select all code. 3 Click the `{}` button, press CTRL+K, or indent every line 4 spaces by hand.

Comment: Add `<string>` to the list of missing includes.

Comment: Odd that this compiles for you. It appears to be missing a couple headers. There may also be one warning. Don't ignore warnings. Compiler errors means the code is cannot be transformed into a program, but warnings mean that while the code can make a program, it probably doesn't do what you want it to do. Warnings are the first line of defense against logic errors so turn the reporting level up, and turn it up **LOUD**.

Comment: According to Code::Blocks there are no errors or warnings. The resolution as to why displayMenu() wouldn't display is simply that it needed to have a new class of Course_directory ie. Course_directory c; followed by c.displayMenu(); and what do you know it works! Thanks soooooo much for all the help